# Using Jquery to pass a variable into part of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with dynamics and I am trying to pull in a variable from the form and use it to create a dynamic URL   Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="new_/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        var $productid = attr("src",parent.window.Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_productid').getValue());
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="word-wrap: break-word;">
    <div style="align: center;">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/products/'+productid+'">Link to some site</a>');
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely it is `$productid` vs `productid`. Remove the `$`. Also, in the future, you should explain what is happening vs what you want/expect to happen. All you're saying now is that something's wrong. It's usually hard to find what's wrong when you don't know what's happening.

Comment: also what is the `attr` function you are calling in the `.ready` callback, JS has no native `attr` global function

Comment: Sorry guess I know even less than I thought about what I'm doing. I used some example code a friend gave me and wrote this, and now that friend is not available to ask for help.

Comment: What is happening instead of showing my Link it shows absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1):

you have 3 problems:

1. `$productid` vs `productid`
2. `$productid` is declared inside the callback function so is not in the same scope as your document.write call
3. Even if `$productid` was in global scope your `document.write` call will more than likely happen before your `$(document).ready` callback so `$productid` will still not contain the value you expect.

So do your js work inside the ready callback, and put a placeholder anchor in your html that you can change once it is ready

HTML

```
<div style="align: center;">
  <a href="#" id="linkToChange">Some text</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $productid = attr("src",parent.window.
                                Xrm.Page.
                                getAttribute('new_productid').getValue());
    $("#linkToChange").attr("href","http://www.mywebsite.com/products/'+$productid);
});
```

Also not sure what the function `attr` you are calling is, as you do not define it anywhere so you are more than likely getting an error for this as well

Answer (score 0):

Your script is running before the variable is even declared, you declare the var in the jQuery `ready()` function, that is occuring AFTER that script block is executed.  Move your js script to a function and have it called after the var is declared in the `ready()` function.

Comment: On top of that, `productid` wasn't ever defined anywhere and even if it was in place of `$productid`, `$productid` wouldn't be in the scope of the other script even if it ran after the `ready()`